# WPF checkbox as button in code behind

Tags: wpf-controls

I want my checkbox to be visible as button. Check-boxes are generated dynamically in code behind file using C#.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please show is some code. Without it is hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

private void loadItems()
        {

```
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "ConString";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ItemId,ItemName from ITEMS", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                iid = (dt.Rows[i]["ItemId"]).ToString();
                iname = dt.Rows[i]["ItemName"].ToString();


                CheckBox btn = new CheckBox();

                btn.Content = iname;
                btn.Height = 20;
                btn.Width = 150;
                btn.Tag = iname;

                //var2 = btn.Tag.ToString();

                wrapItems.Children.Add(btn);
                btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(CheckBoxChecked);
                //btn.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.btnClick(sender,e)));

                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Here i am generating checkbox dynamically based on my data. can i use CheckBox as buttons instead. i want my checkbox to be visible as button.